# Matrix indexing notation syntax

Tags: r, indexing, syntax, notation

Lets create matrix m.

```
m <- matrix(1:9, 3,3, T); m
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    5    6
[3,]    7    8    9

m[3,1]    # 7
m[3][1]   # 7
```

Why does second indexing notation work? Is there difference between these two notations? Is it safe to use?

But sequences behave differently:

```
m[1:2, 1:2]    # works as expected, return matrix
m[1:2][1:2]    # return vector 1 4, why?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `matrix` is a `vector` with `dim` attributes.  By doing the `m[3]`, it returns only the 3rd element.  If we want to use a chained extract, then extract the row with column index blank after the `,` (`drop = FALSE` - in case we want to avoid coercing the matrix to vector) and select the first element which is the first column

```
m[3,, drop = FALSE][1]
#[1] 7
```

---

In the OP's first option, it uses the row index and column index with `3, 1` which selects the element based on both index

---

In the updated example, OP specified row index as first 2 rows and columns as first 2 columns.  So, it returns a matrix omitting the 3rd row and 3rd column

```
m[1:2, 1:2]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    2
#[2,]    4    5
```

But, in the second case

```
m[1:2]
#[1] 1 4
```

extracts the first two elements

likewise, if we do

```
m[1:5]
#[1] 1 4 7 2 5
```

is the first five elements following the columnwise order

Therefore,

```
m[1:2][1:2]
```

returns only 1, 4 because from the first Extract, it is only extracting 1 and 4.  Then, the second extract is based on that subset and it also have 2 elements.  If we increase the index, those positions are not available and filled by NA

```
m[1:2][1:4]
#[1]  1  4 NA NA
```

The elementwise indexing is acting on the `vector`

```
c(m)
#[1] 1 4 7 2 5 8 3 6 9
```

where the first two elements are 1 and 4

Comment: No, I was wondering in general, what is going on? How and why those notation return same value. What is going on when we use [][]? Why it doesnt work with sequences?

Comment: @CoR ir you check `m[3]`, it extracts a single element, then you can only do `m[3][1]` as it is the only element.  In general, for data.frame or matrix, you need both row/column index for extracing an element.  For matrix, if you only specify a single value, it extracts the element from that position. i.e. `m[4]` will get you 2 because it is the 4th element as the positions are calculated column wise

Comment: @CoR I updated the post. Hope it helps you

Comment: So, m[colWiseOrder] That is nice to know. Thanks :)